# React и карта яндекса

Tags: reactjs, яндекс-карты

Срочно нужно вставить карту, но пока только начато знакомство с рекат.

```
const Contact = props => {
  return (
    React.createElement("section", { id: "contact" },));
};
```

Куда нужно добавить код ниже, чтобы всё корректно заработало?

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h3>App</h3>
      <iframe
        src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d274450.6497260677!2d11.596580418800349!3d48.134840853450434!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sde!4v1603744450305!5m2!1sen!2sde"
        width="600"
        height="450"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen=""
        aria-hidden="false"
        tabindex="0"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```